# File watcher in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a web page when user click on a button it should call some script. That's easy to do but that script will create a file in the user directory. Each user has it's own directory and script will be creating new file in that directory. I am using the following code in the Global.asax file.

```
    private FileSystemWatcher fsw;
     public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {           
        string monitorPath = "C:\\testwatcher\\";
        Application.Add("watcher", new FileSystemWatcher(monitorPath));
        fsw = (FileSystemWatcher)Application["watcher"];
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
      }
    public static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);
        string File_Name_format = string.Format("NewFile_{0:yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss_tt}.message", DateTime.Now);
        string File_Path = "C:\\testfilescrated\\" + File_Name_format;
        File.WriteAllText(File_Path, text);
    }
```

I want the file to be creaded in user folder. The user folder name is the same as the user login name. The above code is creating file in "C:\testfilescrated\" location.
How do i copy the file to e.g. if john is logged in and has click button to get file file should be copied to "C:\testfilescrated\john\" directory if any other user is logged in file should be copied to that user folder.

Comment: what happens if you have two Johns?

Comment: @BossRoss user login is unique may be john1 or john_first_letter_of_second_name

Comment: If the file should only be copied when clicking a button, there is no need for a `FileSystemWatcher`. The `FileSystemWatcher` is only useful if you want to monitor changes to a file by another process.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Because the time is not know i mite take an hour when the file is created. If i don't need FileSystemWatcher. what and how can i use when the file is created the user gets notified.

Comment: If your code is not doing the actual file creation and you have to watch for it in `OnCreated`, you won't know in `OnCreated` which user the file applies to, so you need a reference somewhere to match the filename with the username - in a database or a `Dictionary`, something like that

Comment: @Rhumborl how do i do that can you please help me

Comment: for that, we would need to see the code for the button click, which kicks off the process to create the file.

Comment: @Rhumborl button click even and that can contain any code i will be uing some sql scripts to run and create the file but dont know how long will the scripts be running for.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you include the name of the user in the filename then? If you just call a script when someone clicks on the button, you can pass the username along as a parameter, as that's the only time you know which user it belongs to.

Once the script finishes and creates the file, then the filewatcher will know which user it belongs to and you can write code to move the file to the appropriate folder.